# Optimize database query for time series data retrieving using postgresql and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, query-optimization, timeoutexception

Hello guys I'm working on a interesting real time application.
The application is as follows.I have a `meter` model and `meter_info` model

```
calss Meter
  has_many :meter_infos
  # filed: id 
end

class MeterInfo
  belongs_to :meter
  # field: meter_id, voltage 
end
```

In every two minutes a new data is being saved to `meter_info` table.So you can imagine there are a huge data set over there.

Now what I want do is to find out exactly one voltage record of 10 `meters` each at a time in 10 minutes interval within 1 day.
So the result would be something like this

```
id           created_at          meter_id      voltage
2001     2017-10-19 15:40:00        2             100
2001     2017-10-19 15:45:00        1             100
2001     2017-10-19 15:39:00        3             100
2001     2017-10-19 15:48:00        4             100
2001     2017-10-19 15:38:00        5             100
2001     2017-10-19 15:42:00        6             100
...
...
```

I've tried several queries but as it's taking too much time to find out the record, the request gets timeouted. Here is what I have tried for

```
(('2017-07-02 00:00:00').to_datetime.to_i .. 
  ('2017-07-02 23:59:59').to_datetime.to_i).step(10.minutes) do |date|
                query = "SELECT  created_at, meter_id, voltage
                FROM meter_infos
                WHERE created_at between  '#{Time.at(date).utc}' and 
                '#{Time.at(date).utc + 10.minutes}'
                AND meter_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
                ORDER BY id desc limit 1"

                voltages = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)

end
```

Which is timeouted even in the development environment.
Then I've tried to use `Postgresql`'s `generated_series` like below

```
  query= "SELECT meter_id,voltage,  count(id) as ids
              , GENERATE_SERIES( timestamp without time zone '2017-10-19',
                  timestamp without time zone '2017-10-19',
                 '10 min') as time_range
              from meter_infos
              where meter_infos.created_at between '2017-10-19 00:00:01'::timestamp and  '2017-10-19 23:59:59'::timestamp
              and meter_infos.meter_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
                  GROUP BY meter_id, voltage
              ORDER BY meter_id ASC limit 1"

            sbps_plot = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Which is faster but gives me wrong data.
I am using `Ruby on Rails` and `Postgresql`.
Can somebody help me to write the faster query to find out data against time or suggest me any procedure to handle time series data analysis.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you indexed those tables?

Comment: Ideas: There's only a fixed number of 10 minute intervals in a day, right? Just work those out first and get everything back in a single query. 

Or in your query, convert the timestamp to seconds, then perform a `mod` operation against 600 (ten minutes in seconds) and only select records where this gives you remainder between 0 and 119.

Comment: @Justme yes it's already indexed.

Comment: Another hint: I'm pretty sure your first version of the query is just a slow way of getting back all the records. If you step up in 10 minute intervals, then your query covers a 10 minute range, you're going to get back everything. Your query should only cover a 2 minute range starting at 10 minute intervals.

Comment: Show us explain analyze

Comment: @JustMe thanks for your suggestion for indexing.I saw that my index was made against `meter_id`.When I added `created_at` index it gave a great result.I have 2.2M of data in my postgresql database and it took 640 miliseconds to load all my data in 10 minutes of interval at a day.But still I'm not happy enough about the query, there might be good query which would take much less time than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have records every two minutes, but you want to get a sample record from ten minute intervals. Here's my suggested solution:

You can take the modulus of the epoch time of the `created_at` timestamp with 600 (ten minutes in seconds). Then compare this against some 'tolerance' value (e.g. 119 seconds or less) in case the timestamps of your records aren't aligned to perfect ten minute intervals. Think of it of retrieving the first record with a `created_at` inside a 2 minute window following each 10 minute interval of the day.

For example,

```
MeterInfo
  .where(
    meter_id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    created_at: your_date.beginning_of_day..your_date.end_of_day
  )
  .where("(cast(extract(epoch from created_at) as integer) % 600) < 119")
```

Give that a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: It worked for me very well.Thanks for the solution.But I wonder how this `(cast(extract(epoch from created_at) as integer) % 600) < 119")` code actually works.Can you it explain more in details please.I have accepted your answer.Thanks man.

Comment: Sure. `extract(epoch from created_at)` gives you an epoch date/time from the created_at date--this the number of seconds since 00:00 01/01/1970. The `cast(... as integer)` treats this as integer for the purposes of the modulus calculation. The `% 600` performs a modulus division--which gets the remainder after dividing by 600, which we know is 10 minutes in seconds. This gives you a value between 0-600. 00:01 would be 60, 00:05 would be 300, and so on. This works for any time of day, so 13:41 would be 60, 13:45 would be 300.

Comment: Then we want to select records where this is < 119, so within 2 mins of a 10 minute boundary